# React Native Crash Firebase

Tags: android, react-native

I am running React Native android in production and am getting the following error in the Crashes and ANRs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done (AsyncTask.java:415)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance (FirebaseApp.java:183)
  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance
  at com.wix.reactnativenotifications.fcm.FcmToken.refreshToken (FcmToken.java:75)
  at com.wix.reactnativenotifications.fcm.FcmToken.onAppReady (FcmToken.java:65)
  at com.wix.reactnativenotifications.fcm.FcmInstanceIdRefreshHandlerService.onHandleWork (FcmInstanceIdRefreshHandlerService.java:26)
  at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:396)
  at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground (JobIntentService.java:387)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call (AsyncTask.java:394)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
```

I do not have Firebase installed in my package.json.

Any ideas what might be the issue or how to fix it?

Comment: You're using `react-native-notifications` which depend on Firebase cloud messaging to push notification on Android.

Comment: Review setup instruction here - https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/installation-android